# Using Aura outside of Salesforce

Tags: aura

I recently dived into Lightning and the Aura framework and I'm really wondering why you would choose Aura over any other framework. Of course in Salesforce you have no choice but what about the outside world?

The only reason I can think of is to use SLDS and Aura to create the same "Salesforce experience" outside of Salesforce. But if that's the only reason for using Aura I'm not quite sure that it will gain much widespread use.

And for a JavaScript framework it feels way to clunky and declarative rather then being just JavaScript.

Also: Is anybody besides Salesforce using Aura?

Comment: Take into account that you can use SLDS w/ React, for example and therefor have the same Salesforce experience outside of Salesforce. SLDS is just CSS.

Comment: That is true of course. I was just thinking of "experience" in a broader sense which would also include developers. But I noticed that this is confusing - thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use SLDS and not aura to create Salesforce experience outside of Salesforce,  I have seen the couple of products that use SLDS css and Vue, Angular to create Single page application. Aura was created by Salesforce just 6 years back and has limited support in forums like stack-overflow so external non-sf customers don't fancy using for the enterprise-grade application. That does not mean its a bad framework, it's just in its maturing phase.

When salesforce designed aura, its primary objective was to make it compatible for new lightning experience, to make it a worldwide accepted framework which can be used anywhere was the secondary or ternary objective.

Just check number of people watching for Angular.
[image]

And when you compare this with aura:
[image]

https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura

This directly means its harder to find resources who are good with Aura, debugging and if you reach a roadblock there isn't much expertise available in the market that would help you go forward.

So if you ask my personal view, No I would not recommend anyone to build their non-SF enterprise app using the Aura framework.

Comment: Specially when you have React, Vue, etc... I sometimes even find some features to be easier with React and a container than with LC.

Comment: Yeah, Thats how I got in love with React.